# Why does apk signing with jarsigner give java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException: SHA11 MessageDigest not available?

Tags: java, android, apk, jarsigner

I'm trying to sign an apk with a keystore.

When I enter this:

```
\bin>jarsigner -verbose -sigalg SHA1withRSA -digestalg SHA11 -keystore .mykeystore MY.apk ALIAS
Enter Passphrase for keystore:
```

I get this error:

> jarsigner error: java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException: SHA11 MessageDigest not available

Any clue why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**tl;dr** A typo in the name of the digest algorithm `SHA1`.

It should be `-digestalg SHA1` (not `-digestalg SHA11`).